# eigenvalues of inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation violate superposition using FEM

Tags: finite-element, eigenvalues, eigensystem, fenics, helmholtz-equation

I am trying to solve the in-homogeneous Helmholtz equation with damping and forcing using finite element method (FEM) with [FEniCSx](https://fenicsproject.discourse.group/t/dolfinx-violates-superposition-law-for-an-eigenvalue-problem-with-slepc/12890). The equation is;

$c^2\nabla^2p - c^2\omega i d \nabla^2p + \omega^2 p = f$

where the $d$ is the damping parameter, the $i$ is complex number, the f is the forcing, the $\omega$ is the eigenvalue and the $p$ is the eigenvector. In matrix form;

$(\mathbf{A} + \omega \mathbf{B} + \omega^2 \mathbf{C})\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{D}\mathbf{p} $

where $\mathbf{B}$ is the damping matrix and $\mathbf{D}$ is the forcing matrix. For 1D case, the boundary conditions are Neumann boundary at both ends.

I am aiming to damp the system with $\mathbf{B}$ and did try 4 different cases;

- $\mathbf{A} + \omega^2 \mathbf{C} = 0 $ (no damping and no forcing)
- $\mathbf{A} + \omega \mathbf{B} + \omega^2 \mathbf{C} = 0$ (damping and no forcing)
- $(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{D}) + \omega^2 \mathbf{C} = 0 $ (no damping and forcing)
- $(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{D}) + \omega \mathbf{B} + \omega^2 \mathbf{C} = 0 $ (damping and forcing)

When I run this cases, I get very weird behaviour. Here is the list of the eigenvalues for the cases;

- $\mathbf{A} + \omega^2 \mathbf{C} = 0 $ gives $\omega=1069.2399-0j$
- $\mathbf{A} + \omega \mathbf{B} + \omega^2 \mathbf{C} = 0$ gives $\omega=1139.6967-0.2463j$
- $(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{D}) + \omega^2 \mathbf{C} = 0 $ gives $\omega=1074.748+3.2431j$
- $(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{D}) + \omega \mathbf{B} + \omega^2 \mathbf{C} = 0 $ gives $\omega=1146.0758+3.5129j$

The complex part of the eigenvalue is representing the growth rate of the system. As I impose a damping, the last case's complex part (+3.5129j) should be lower than the 3. case's complex part (3.2431j) according to the law of superposition but it is not.

Would anyone can enlight me about what I am doing wrong, I am struggling with this for more than a week.

Thank you!

Comment: Usually, the forced Helmholtz equation is not an eigenvalue problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, the forcing is a function of an eigenvalue $\omega$. Hence I find the matrix D iteratively and I use a method called fixed point iteration. The fundamental paper about this problem stated in Section IV.B in https://hal.science/file/index/docid/908192/filename/paper.pdf

Comment: Which eigenvalues are being shown here? The one with the largest magnitude? Largest real part?

Comment: These eigenvalues belong to 1st axial mode of the 1m tube.

Comment: Usually the principle of superposition is used to construct solutions from linear combinations of others. It is not clear to me what the principle of superposition has to do with solutions of a perturbed nonlinear eigenvalue problem.

Comment: @EkremEkici, you can have the forcing function depending on $\omega$ values that are not eigenvalues.

Comment: @whpowell96 The eigenvalue problem become linear. It is more clear from eq (46) in [this](https://hal.science/file/index/docid/908192/filename/paper.pdf) paper.

Comment: @nicoguaro Sure, but it is not the case for my problem.

Comment: Even though you are approximating the solution via a sequence of standard eigenvalue problems, the problem you are attempting to solve is a quadrativ eigenvalue problem and you are trying to udnerstand the effect of perturbing one of the matrices in the problem via a damping matrix. I don't see any easy way of analyzing the effect of this perturbation.